# RasPi and XBee communication

Tags: xbee

I am using XBee module to communicate between a PC and a Raspberry Pi. I wrote following code:

PC:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial(1) #opened COM2
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.open()
ser.write('hello')
```

Raspberry Pi:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600)
ser.open()
ser.read()
```

I can see that transmission led on the XBee on PC side is glowing and detecting the network, and if I short Tx, Rx on RasPi side I get the loopback, but I don't get any values when I run the second code on RasPi. I am using AT mode, both configured as routers.

Answer (score 2):

I made a silly mistake. I should have connected Rx(of receiver) to Rx of Pi and Tx also in the same way. It was my fault.